# PyQt5 not found by Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3, gui, modules

I installed Python 3.7 on my raspberry pi with the help of [Installing Python 3.7.0 on Raspbian](https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/6a5a30ebc8f79936fa136c524417761d) tutorial and wanted to use it to start my script which uses PyQt5 but its throwing a ModuleNotFoundError. PyQt5 is installed and working with 3.4.2 why is it not working with 3.7 ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install an out-of-distribution Python version and expect system Python packages to work. They're compiled for Python 3.5 that's included in the distribution.

I suggest you upgrade to Buster (unreleased/testing) to get system Python 3.7 and PyQt from the distribution.

To upgrade to Buster, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `stretch` with `buster` on both lines, then run `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Wait, are you on Raspbian Jessie? First start from a new Stretch image, then upgrade to Buster.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to [Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi)

I used the recommended version for ARMv7, though Raspi3 has actually a ARMv8 processor. Ubuntu has, compared to Raspbian, a newer version of Python3 as part of the system.
I had to fiddle with the config file a little bit, offset and stuff. Make sure you have the right keyboard layout before changing the password after starting the first time. Then I upgraded the whole system first, inclusive dist-upgrade, which took some rounds. Then I had to install python3-pyqt5, and then Electrum worked. I ran it with 'run_electrum', I didn't try to install it.

If you stay with Raspbian, you'll need to compile PyQt on your own. Do not try to upgrade your whole system to Buster, it might fail completely and need a new install of the whole OS.